# C# как разделить на равные части и записать в строковый массив?

Tags: c#, строки

```c
string str = "001010101001";
```

Нужно разделить `str` на части по 4 символа и записать в строковый массив.
Т.е.

a[0]="0010" a[1]="1010" a[2]="1001"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/1450797 Вероятно, это то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
// длина строки должна быть кратна 4, иначе ничего не получится
string text = "001010101001";
string[] a = new string[text.Length / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    a[i] = text.Substring(i * 4, 4);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, a));
```

```
0010
1010
1001
```

Еще можно так

```cs
a[i] = text[i * 4, i * 4 + 4];
```

Или вообще вот так без цикла, но нужен .NET 6

```cs
string[] a = text.Chunk(4).Select(x => new string(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @aepot text.Chunk - классное нововведение, можно ли аналогичным образом сослаться, допустим, на середину массива байт без всяких костыльных классов-линкеров? Допустим создал массив byte[16] (arr_0_15), и мне нужно только 4 байта начиная с 4го байта (отсчёт с нуля) как массив byte[4] (arr_4_7), или аналогичным образом. Только так, что если я меняю arr_4_7[1] то по сути меняю arr_0_15[5]. Опять-же без костыльных классов с кастомными индексаторами и без указателей на моей стороне. Подобная реализация есть в фреймворке?

Comment: @Blackmeser спаны же `var span = arr.AsSpan()[4..7]; span[1] = 42;`

Comment: @aepot хм, то что надо, пора уже полноценно переезжать на .net core, а то с 4.7 утонуть можно. Ну всё, чанки minecraft, держитесь.